# Compute the Gradient of the following functions.

Tags: vector-analysis

I am a undegraduate math major student. I have met a problem about gradient and I am comfused about it.

Compute the Gradient of the following functions:

(a) s(**r**) = sin (kr)/r

(b) s(**r**) = cos (kr)/r

(Here r is the absolute value of r.)

What is the difference between this one and

(a) s(**r**) = sin (**k·r**)

(b) s(**r**) = cos (**k·r**)?

Thank you very much for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

In $s(\vec{r}) = \frac{\sin(kr)}{r}$ the right hand side is a function of $r=|\vec r|$ alone. So it takes the same value at all points on a circle (or sphere if you are working in three dimension) around the origin. Hence its gradient must always be radial - the gradient will take the form $\nabla s= f(r)\vec r$.

However in $s(\vec r) = \sin(\vec k \cdot \vec r)$ the right hand side is a function of $r$ *and* of the angle between $\vec r$ and $\vec k$. Even if we keep $r$ constant then $\vec k \cdot \vec r$ varies in value from $|\vec k||\vec r|$ to $-|\vec k||\vec r|$.